# inner HTML returns nothing when contains h2,h3

Tags: javascript, vba, innerhtml

I am trying to run through the data on a web page, and then present it in Excel for easier reading, and that the data changes each day (its an application feed compiled overnight).  I am using VBA, with MS HTML and and MS Internet Controls, using

HTML

```
<SPAN id="elementname">THIS DATA I WANT</SPAN>
```

VBA

```
set ele=htmlDoc.getElementByID("elementname")
clsApplication.whatever=trim(ele.innerHTML)
```

This has works fine, however, it innerHTML returns nothing when the HTML is like so

```
<SPAN id="elementname"><h2>Element 1</h2><h3>Element 1 data</h3>THIS DATA I WANT</SPAN>
```

`ele.getElementsByTagName("h2").length` returns 0

I understand that its not the same as the earlier example, but cant seem to get at the data.

Can anyone advise?

Many thanks

Comment: It's `.innerHTML` in javascript, not .innerHtml, unelss that's a vb thing. I'm a bit confused that you don't find any tags either.

Comment: Apologies, i didnt cut and past the code, i was using innerHTML from intellisense.

Comment: I have just looked at finding the string within the inner html of the main div, rather than looking via, view source, and the html cioming back has set it to be <span id="elementname"></span><h2>XYZ</h2>

Comment: Thanks for the input on this.

Comment: The code you show works fine for me with a page containing the HTML you posted.  I get the expected innerHTML output and "1" as the output for the last line.

Answer (score 2):

### Solution

The `innerHtml` property contains nothing, you are looking for `innerHTML` (case sensitive) ([MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML)).

Try accessing `ele.innerHTML` and it should work properly.

---

### Possible structure issue

I would also suggest that you double-check your HTML structure, as it might lead you to some errors in the future ([inline elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Inline_elemente) cannot contain [block elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements)).

Why?

> **Formatting**
> By default, block-level elements begin on new lines.
>
> **Content model**
> Generally, block-level elements may contain inline elements and other block-level elements. Inherent in this structural distinction is the idea that block elements create "larger" structures than inline elements.

(Taken from the [block elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements#Block-level_vs._inline) documentation)

Generated HTML will looks something like this:

```
<span></span><h1></h1><h2></h2>text text
```

so the span ***might*** be empty, it only depends on how the browser will build the broken HTML document.

Comment: That (case sensitivity) is *not* the case when accessing the DOM from VBA (and using late binding):  `IE.document.body.InNerHtMl` works just fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

`<span>` tags are inline elements and cannot contain block elements like `<h2>` or `<h3>`, meaning that's incorrect HTML markup.

Comment: Would anyone know another way around it?  I can do it by getting the body innerhtml and searching for what i want, but didnt want to do it that way :)